# Download base64 encoded zip file I receive from server

Tags: javascript, formatting, format, zip

I'm receiving a base64 encoded zip file from the server,and I have to save it.

When I first receive the string it looks like this:
[image]

After that, if I `atob(content)`, it looks like this:
[image]

Minimal reproducible code that can be run with node:

```
const fs = require(`fs`)
const fetch = require(`node-fetch`)
const JSZip = require(`jszip`)

function logMainFile(blob){
  const zip = new JSZip();
  zip.loadAsync(blob).then(function(zip) {
    zip.file(`main.py`).async(`string`).then(function (content) {
      console.log(content);
    });
  })
}

async function getFileFromGitlab() {
  const url = `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/47987400/repository/files/products%2Fcuore%2Fcuore.zip?ref=main`

  const text = await fetch(url)
  const data = await text.json()
  const blob = atob(data?.content);

  // This is here just to show the data is there
  logMainFile(blob)

  fs.writeFileSync(`test.zip`, blob)

}

getFileFromGitlab()
```

The problem is that I can't open the file, it seems to be corrupted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [**not** a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212)_). What is `content`, exactly? `new Blob([ atob(content) ], { type: "application/zip" })` should work. How is `content` generated? Looks like a backend problem, not a frontend problem. If the file is downloaded before getting zipped, make sure _all_ chunks of the download are included.

Comment: Ok, I add a minimal reproducible example that can be run with node

Comment: I downloaded the provided url, pulled out the content, and decoded the base64. The result was a perfectly valid zip file. There's nothing wrong with what you're downloading.

Comment: I know. The problem is when I download it and save it as a file locally

Comment: Anyway, I found the problem, I just had to transforme it to bytes before saving it. I did that using `function str2bytes (str: string) {
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length)
        for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i)
        }
        return bytes
    }`
I cant answer the question because its marked as CLOSED

Comment: Why is the server sending it in base64 in the first place, and not just the binary content? It seems unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: I don't controll the server. It's actually gitlab.com, I don't know why they send us like that. Anyway, I already fund the answer and posted it in my last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I just had to transforme it to bytes before saving it. I did that using

```
function str2bytes (str: string) {         
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length)         
    for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {             
        bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i)         
    }         
    return bytes     
}
```